# received signal exits program but does not call signal handler

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, signals

### **Problem**

After my program runs within the main thread, I send a signal.SIGINT signal to interrupt the program and cause an exit to occur. The program shuts down, however the signal handler is not called for some reason, I need the signal handler to call to run some cleanup code.

### **Background Info**

Currently I'm running on:
- Windows 10
- Python 3.7.3 x64

I've tried sending multiple different signals such as SIGINT, SIGTERM and CTRL_C_EVENT from the builtin signals module. In all cases, the program flow is interrupted and the program exits, however the signal_handler is not called.

I'm aware that all signals are only received by the main function, so that is something I have tried to adhere to within the code.

### **Code**

**Where:**
client = discordpy client object from the rewrite
init_sanic() = initialises the sanic web framework

```py
class ForcedShutdown(Exception):
    """
    Custom exception to be raised
    """
    pass


def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print(f'signal received is {signal}')
    raise ForcedShutdown

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    try:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

        client = DiscordBot()
        bot_thread = Thread(target=lambda : client.run(setup_pars['CLIENT_TOKEN']))
        api_thread = Thread(target=lambda : init_sanic())

        threads = [api_thread, bot_thread]
        for x in threads:
            x.start()

        while True:
            time.sleep(100)

    except (ForcedShutdown, SystemExit):
        print('DO SHUTDOWN ACTIONS')
```

**The output:**

```
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [DEBUG] 

                 Sanic
         Build Fast. Run Fast.


[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [INFO] Starting worker [11808]
Discord Bot Loaded
```

**Code used to send the signal:**

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

**Final output:**

```
Process finished with exit code 2
```

### **Expected Output**

While the code exits as expected, the outputs is:

```
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [DEBUG] 

                 Sanic
         Build Fast. Run Fast.


[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [INFO] Starting worker [11808]
Discord Bot Loaded

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Whereas the expected final output is:

```
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [DEBUG] 

                 Sanic
         Build Fast. Run Fast.


[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [WARNING] Sanic tried to use loop.add_signal_handler but it is not implemented on this platform.
[2019-07-31 19:49:18 +0100] [11808] [INFO] Starting worker [11808]
Discord Bot Loaded
DO SHUTDOWN ACTIONS

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Thanks for any help!